# FFMPEG audio normaliser dynaudnorm does no impact to amix

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Basically I am mixing multiple mp3 files with `amix` and `adelay`.

The issue I got is that the very first mp3 volume is low and the last one is too loud, exactly same what discussed in this post: [FFMPEG amix filter volume issue with inputs of different duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509147/ffmpeg-amix-filter-volume-issue-with-inputs-of-different-duration)

I have followed @Gyan's solution by adding these options to amix `:duration=first:dropout_transition=0,dynaudnorm` but it does no impact to the output.

[image]

My command is simply like this:

```
ffmpeg \
-i "video.mp4" \
-i "audio1.mp3" \
-i "audio2.mp3" \
-i "audio3.mp3" \
-y \
-filter_complex " \
    [a:0]volume=0[videoAudio]; \
    [1]adelay=500[ad1]; \
    [2]adelay=5400[ad2]; \
    [3]adelay=10000[ad3]; \
    [videoAudio][ad1][ad2][ad3]amix=inputs=4:duration=first:dropout_transition=0,dynaudnorm \
" \
output.mp3
```

Any idea how to get `dynaudnorm` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `[a:0]volume=0[videoAudio]; \`

If you're silencing the video soundtrack, why not leave it out entirely?

> `[1]adelay=500[ad1]; \`

If your mp3-files are stereo, then you have to specify the delay for both channels.

> `duration=first`

By delaying your inputs, `audio3.mp3` will automatically become the longest:

```
[ delay 500ms ]<audio1.mp3>|
[                          |       delay 5400ms ]<audio2.mp3>
[                          |                                   delay 10000ms ]<audio3.mp3>
```

The vertical line (immediately after `audio1.mp3`) marks the end-of-stream with `duration=first`. In this case you really want the default `duration=longest`!

> `dropout_transition=0`

I suggest to set this option to the total length of your mix, followed by the `volume` filter set to the amount of inputs, to restore the volume.

To find out the total length of your mix:

```
ffmpeg \
-i "audio1.mp3" \
-i "audio2.mp3" \
-i "audio3.mp3" \
-lavfi "
  [0]adelay=500|500[ad1];
  [1]adelay=5400|5400[ad2];
  [2]adelay=10000|10000[ad3];
  [ad1][ad2][ad3]amix=inputs=3
" \
-f null -
```

Let's say this returns `time=00:01:30.74` for instance. Then the final command would be:

```
ffmpeg \
-i "audio1.mp3" \
-i "audio2.mp3" \
-i "audio3.mp3" \
-lavfi "
  [0]adelay=500|500[ad1];
  [1]adelay=5400|5400[ad2];
  [2]adelay=10000|10000[ad3];
  [ad1][ad2][ad3]amix=inputs=3:dropout_transition=90.74,volume=3,dynaudnorm
" \
output.mp3
```

**[edit]**
If you say you've read Gyan's answer with the url you provided, then I don't understand why I still had to tell you about `duration=first` and `dropout_transition=0`. Let me show you the significance of `dropout_transition`.

```
ffmpeg \
-i "input1.mp3" -i "input2.mp3" -i "input3.mp3" \
-lavfi "[1]adelay=11233[ad2];[2]adelay=20141[ad3];[0][ad2][ad3]amix=inputs=3" \
-f null -
[...]
size=N/A time=00:00:33.43 bitrate=N/A speed= 134x
```

I tested 3 samples. The total length of the audio-mix is `33.43`seconds.

This is how the waveform would look like with `dropout_transition=0`:

```
ffmpeg \
-i "input1.mp3" -i "input2.mp3" -i "input3.mp3" \
-lavfi "
  [1]adelay=11233[ad2];[2]adelay=20141[ad3];
  [0][ad2][ad3]amix=inputs=3:dropout_transition=0,
  volume=3,showwavespic=s=639x128
" \
"ffmpeg_amix=dt=0,vol=3,wavespic.png"
```

[image: ffmpeg_amix=dt=0,vol=3,wavespic]
Just as the waveform in your original post; the end gets very loud. So this has nothing to do with `dynaudnorm`.

With the `dropout_transition` set to the total length of the audio-mix (and don't forget `volume=3`) this is how the waveform should look like:

```
ffmpeg \
-i "input1.mp3" -i "input2.mp3" -i "input3.mp3" \
-lavfi "
  [1]adelay=11233[ad2];[2]adelay=20141[ad3];
  [0][ad2][ad3]amix=inputs=3:dropout_transition=33.43,
  volume=3,showwavespic=s=639x128
" \
"ffmpeg_amix=dt=33.43,vol=3,wavespic.png"
```

[image: ffmpeg_amix=dt=33.43,vol=3,wavespic]

Next you should play with `dynaudnorm` its parameters, as Paul B. Mahol mentioned:

```
ffmpeg \
-i "input1.mp3" -i "input2.mp3" -i "input3.mp3" \
-lavfi "
  [1]adelay=11233[ad2];[2]adelay=20141[ad3];
  [0][ad2][ad3]amix=inputs=3:dropout_transition=33.43,
  volume=3,dynaudnorm=f=200:g=15,showwavespic=s=639x128
" \
"ffmpeg_amix=dt=33.43,vol=3,dynaudnorm=f=200-g=15,wavespic.png"
```

[image: ffmpeg_amix=dt=33.43,vol=3,dynaudnorm=f=200-g=15,wavespic]

I'm more a fan of the `acompressor`-filter btw:

[image: ffmpeg_amix=dt=33.43,vol=3,acomp=l=2-t=-30dB-a=200-r=1000-d=0-mu=+5.1dB,wavespic]
**[/edit]**

Comment: `[a:0]volume=0` I was just playing with the volumes.. but it's something should be in the command. My audio files are mono so it was ok to leave `adelay`'s like they are.

Comment: Actually your answer is one of the solutions in the post I linked above, but it doesn't answer my question which is about `dynaudnorm` option that do nothing in my case as it's explained in that answer by @Gyan here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38714779/3632172

Comment: that was a really WELL explained answer... so as I understood that dynaudnorm needs to be set to make it work! Just Gyan's answer didn't explain anything and I was a bit confused that it's something wrong my code!

Comment: Before a night from posting this question on, I went with that solution where you set `dropout_transition` to the most delayed input with adding its duration as well, then I set the volume to number of inputs and it did the trick. I am considering to use `acompressor` for better outputs quality. I appreciate again the help Reino ;) thanks a lot

Comment: @parse You're welcome. You may find https://stackoverflow.com/q/57190018/2703456 (on the `acompressor`-filter) also interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Please consult dynaudnorm documentation, it clearly explains everything. Specifically duration defaults are very high, thus normalization never kicks in. You need to change first two options of dynaudnorm filter: f (framelen) and g (gausssize) to much lower values.

Comment: Yeah, I played its params and showed me some changes. thanks ;)